# what is bad text index in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am a `tkinter` beginner and I would like to ask what is this

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\2.py", line 23, in <module>
    box.insert( "win2",x)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3272, in insert
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "win2"
```

although i change 'win2' to others but the error still have
they said the word is bad text index

this is my code:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import*
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext

x= "ww"
a = 0
qty = 10

win2 = Tk()
win2.title ("abc  ")
win2.geometry ("400x400")
win2.maxsize (400,400)
win2.configure(bg= 'white')

box = scrolledtext.ScrolledText (win2, wrap = WORD, width = 29, height = 13, font = ("courier", 10))
box.place (x = 10, y= 10)

while a != qty :
    a= a + 1
    
    box.insert( "win2",x)


    box.config (state= 'disabled')
```

after i removed

```
box.insert( "win2",x)
```

the code can run without error

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of your error traceback is as follows:
`self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)` means that the `insert` method called on your widget (`self._w`), takes an `index`, and `chars` as arguments. (it is `TclTk` syntax for python `text.insert(ndx, chars)`)

`tkinter.TclError: bad text index "win2"` means that the argument `"win2"` provided is not a valid index for this method call.

`tk.Text` indices are **`strings`** of the form `line.column`

from [Dr Shipman's documents](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html):

> An index is a general method of specifying a position in the content
> of a text widget. An index is a string with one of these forms:
>
> ```
> 'line.column'
> ```
>
> The position just before the given column (counting from zero) on the given line (counting from one). Examples: '1.0' is the position of
> the beginning of the text; '2.3' is the position before the fourth
> character of the second line.

Answer (score 1):

the first argument in insert() is meant to be the index you want to insert text. like *"1.0"* for line 1, character 0.

EDIT:

<strike>http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.insert-method</strike>

See **Inserting Initial Text** on https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-text/

Comment: Link is broken. Please update

Answer (score 1):

The insert method of the tkinter text widget takes [text index](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html) of where to insert the text as argument, which cannot be a random string like `"win2"`, thus it throws the error `bad text index "win2"`.

The general function syntax for insert is -:

```
text_widget_object.insert(text_index, text_to_insert, tags = None) # tags is an optional argument.
```

Further info on the insert method can be found [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-methods.html).

> .insert(index, text, tags=None)
>
> Inserts the given text at the given
> index.
>
> If you omit the tags argument, the newly inserted text will be tagged
> with any tags that apply to the characters both before and after the
> insertion point.
>
> If you want to apply one or more tags to the text you are inserting,
> provide as a third argument a tuple of tag strings. Any tags that
> apply to existing characters around the insertion point are ignored.
> Note: The third argument must be a tuple. If you supply a list
> argument, Tkinter will silently fail to apply the tags. If you supply
> a string, each character will be treated as a tag.

Also, from what it seems like you are trying to loop around and insert text on 10 lines of the widget if so, the code for the same is as below -:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext

x= "ww"
a = 0
qty = 10

win2 = Tk()
win2.title ("abc  ")
win2.geometry ("400x400")
win2.maxsize (400,400)
win2.configure(bg= 'white')

box = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(win2, wrap = WORD, width = 29, height = 13, font = ("courier", 10))
box.place (x = 10, y= 10)

while a != (qty + 1) : # For 10 lines (qty + 1), as line 10 is represented by 10.0 unlike index notation.
    a += 1
    
    index_str = str(a) + '.0' # generating the index notation
    box.insert(index_str, x + '\n') # inserting the string

    #box.config(state= 'disabled') # NOTE: This disables, your scrolled text widget and you wont be able to insert more to it.
```

**NOTE:** If you are trying to insert into multiple lines using the loop, note that the last line of the loop body i.e. `box.config(state = 'disabled')` will disable the scrolled text widget, and any further insertions would not show effect on it, to see the effects, it is suggested to comment it/not use it at all, depending on your use case.

---

Two common use cases are described below further customization can be done, using the knowledge of the [text indices](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html), and the syntax as provided above.

If you have to insert the text at the end of the text widget, the last index of the text widget is set as a tkinter constant namely `tkinter.END`. Now we can insert the text at the end like so -:

```
box.insert(tkinter.END, x)
```

Further if the text has to be inserted to the very start of the text widget, then you can use the line index `"1.0"` like so -:

```
box.insert("1.0", x)
```